# Global section of tensor product of line bundles on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $L_1, L_2$ as two line bundles on a smooth projective curve $C$ of  with $h^0(L_1)=0$ and $h^0(L_2)=0$. Does that mean $h^0(L_1 \otimes L_2)=0$?

Does this follow from the universal property of sheafification? I am aware that there exists counterexamples to $h^0(L_1) \otimes h^0(L_2)$ being equal to $h^0(L_1 \otimes L_2)$. But it seems that it's true when both of them do not have sections.

Can anyone briefly explain the argument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are non-trivial two torsion elements in the Picard group . If $L$ is one such, it has no sections, but its square has a section.

Comment: @Mohan, If we impose some extra conditions such as  $g(C) \geq 2, L_1 \neq L_2$ and $\text{deg}(L_2) <0$, then can we conclude $h^0(L_1 \otimes L_2) =0$?

Comment: If $g\geq 2$, take $L_1$ to be a general line bundle of degree one, it has no sections. Take $L_2$ to be the inverse of $L_1$, which has degree $-1$.

Comment: @ Mohan, again in my case I have that degree of $ L_1$ is atleast $10$ and $ L_2$ is not the inverse of $ L_1$

Comment: If degree is 10 and has no global sections, then genus must be at least 11. So, clarify your question.

Comment: @Mohan, yes in my case genus is atleast $50$. I didn't mention that as I earlier thought that it's not necessary for vanishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but let me make a statement answering your question negatively.

Let  $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ and let $d$ be a positive integer with $d<g$. Then there exists a line bundle $L_1$ of degree $d$ with no sections and a line bundle $L_2$ of degree $-1$ (obviously has no sections) such that $L_1\otimes L_2$ has a nonzero section. If $d>1$, clearly $L_2$ is not the inverse of $L_1$.

For this, let $P_r=\operatorname{Pic}^r X$, the set of all line bundles of degree $r$. These are all isomorphic and has dimension $g$. Since $d<g$ and the set of line bundles of degree $d$ with a section has dimension atmost $d$, a general element of $P_d$ has no sections. Fix such an $L_1$. The multiplication map $P_0\to P_d$, $M\mapsto M\otimes L_1$ is an isomorphism, so there exists an $M$ such that $M\otimes L_1$ has a nonzero section. Fix this $M$. So, $M\otimes L_1=O(P_1+\cdots+P_d)$, for some points $P_i$. Now, take $L_2=M\otimes O(-P_1)$.